# Eclipse on Mac throwing Error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/LWJGLException"

Tags: java, runtime-error, lwjgl

*Immediate disclaimer: I've been using LWJGL since 2010. I am currently stuck coding in Eclipse on a 2009 Macbook for reasons out of my control. This error has never popped up for me before, and once I'm back on Windows it never will again.*

So I'm currently trying to set up a LWJGL project, and during the initial steps of getting a window running, the program will refuse to run, throwing this error:

> Error: Unable to initialize main class Boot
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/LWJGLException

Now, I know the problem is with the Native Libraries not being loaded. However, I have the LWJGL.jar file pointing to *Natives/macosx/*, but it's still throwing this error.

Can somebody tell me what's going on, how many .dylib files should be in Natives/macosx, and how to resolve it without just installing Windows 7 and coding on there.

Comment: I assume you're using Java 11?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I used IntelliJ IDE, so try to go into your eclipse 
settings => dependency and make sure that the below-mentioned dependencies are included
(**especially the versions and the type of OS**).

[image]